# Linux: Get "user-friendly" network interface name

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I'm writing a program where the user shall select some network interface under Linux like shown here:

```
Please select a network card:
1)  enp2s0
2)  wlan3
3)  ppp2
```

Up to this point I have no problem.

However, I'd like the users to see more "descriptive" names like shown here:

```
Please select a network card:
1)  PCI Ethernet (enp2s0)
2)  Wireless LAN (wlan3)
3)  Dial-up connection (ppp2)
```

Questions:

- Does Linux know such descriptive names for network interfaces at all?
- If yes: How can I get these names?
- If no: Is there a way to guess the user-friendly name from the interface name with a quite high reliability?
  Example: "ppp*" => "Dial-up connection"; "wl*" => "Wireless network"
  Maybe in combination with the code from `/sys/class/net/.../type`?
- If yes: Where can I find a list of possible interface names?

I know that Gnome desktop lists network interface names like "PCI Ethernet" in the network status drop-down menu. So there must be some method to get a "descriptive" name of some network interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Linux know "friendly" names for network interfaces at all?

No.

> If no: Is there a way to guess the user-friendly name from the interface name with a quite high reliability?

You can probably make the generalizations you have suggested. If you are on a `systemd` based systems, take a look at the [systemd net naming scheme](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html), which shows the prefixes used for different interface types:

```
+--------+------------------------------------+
| Prefix |            Description             |
+--------+------------------------------------+
| en     | Ethernet                           |
| ib     | InfiniBand                         |
| sl     | serial line IP (slip)              |
| wl     | Wireless local area network (WLAN) |
| ww     | Wireless wide area network (WWAN   |
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

> Maybe in combination with the code from /sys/class/net/.../type?

I'm not sure that `type` information is going to be helpful. E.g., both ethernet and wireless interfaces show `type` of `1`. On the other hand, you can positively identify ppp interfaces, for example, using this value.

The possible values for `type` are available in [`if_arp.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/if_arp.h#L29).

Answer (score -1):

these are native naming policies systemd uses. with the old naming (eth0,wlan0,...) an interface name was not predictable (for example, your first eth card could get a name other than eth0) and this caused all sorts of problems. new naming standard assigns name to the interface according to one of the following:

1. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board devices (example: eno1)
2. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: ens1)
3. Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)
4. Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: enx78e7d1ea46da)
5. Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: eth0)

systemd will start by 1, falling back to 2,3,...

[Source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

EDIT:

I should add, if you read the link which I posted, you can use your own names!

> You create your own manual naming scheme, for example by naming your interfaces "internet0", "dmz0" or "lan0". For that create your own .link files in /etc/systemd/network/, that choose an explicit name or a better naming scheme for one, some, or all of your interfaces. See systemd.link(5) for more information.

Comment: This does not help me at all. I **know** the "system" name of the interface (e.g. "enp2s0") and want to know the description (e.g. "Wireless network").

Comment: @MartinRosenau , well this is obvious from the prefix. en==ethernet, wl==Wlan,...

Comment: This is what I actually wanted to do if there is no other solution. Unfortunately, I already found 17 different prefixes (wl, ww, vmnet, vboxnet, en, em, eth, teredo, ppp, sl, pan, ib, tun, sit, ip6tnl, gre and lo) and I'm not sure if my list is complete.

Comment: @MartinRosenau , yes there will be many names in that list. I recommend you to make categories. for example, there are tap devices, tun devices, ethernet devices, wireless devices and so on... for tap and tun and gre devices you ( or the process creating them) can name them. if you just need to list physical devices, you should ignore tap,tun,gre and such devices.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: I updated the answer, please read the link! ;)